# Interrupt loading of site by condition in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are multiple files which should be uploaded and waiting for output. It opens up an AJAX like window during processing. If processing takes too much time, *Close* button should be clicked on this window and file should be submitted again.

I try to use code below, but doesn't click *Close* button in 10 seconds.

```
public void clickOnSendButton() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement webElement;
        try {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(sendButton).click();
            log.info("Processing in progress!");
            webElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("button-download")));
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            webElement = null;
        } finally {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        if (webElement == null) {
            driver.findElement(popUpClose).click();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            driver.findElement(sendButton).click();
        }
}
```

Comment: do it throw some exception?

Comment: @Infern0 : No, it has no effect.

Comment: check if popupclose/sendButton locator isnt finding 2 elements.

Comment: According to the Selenium docs, you should not use implicit and explicit waits together. According to the Selenium contributors, you shouldn't be using implicit waits at all.

Comment: @Infern0 : These are valid identifiers. I use some debug and found `webElement` is not null, but `button-download` is also not visible.

Comment: @JeffC : Yes, but value of implicitlyWait should be temporarily decreased to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'visibilityOfElementLocated' condition instead of 'presenceOfElementLocated' as below:

```
webElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("button-download")));
```

Using the loop:

```
try {
      driver.findElement(By.id("button-submit")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);//3 seconds
      log.info("Processing in progress!");

      for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
        try{
          webElement = driver.findElement(By.className("button-download"));
        } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        if(webElement.isDisplayed())
          break;
        else
          Thread.sleep(1000);
      }

    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} finally {
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    if (!webElement.isDisplayed() ) {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/button/span[1]")).click();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.id("button-submit")).click();
    }
```

Comment: I changed it, but loading is not interrupted after 4 seconds.

Comment: @plaidshirt could u try validating the condition `if (webElement.isDisplayed())` instead of validating it to null?

Comment: I tried it already, but it should be `!(webElement.isDisplayed())` to be same condition.

Comment: oh!. Ok then. @plaidshirt, could you share me the xpaths (or locators) for 'sendbutton' and 'popUpClose' elements? I will try to share you the entire method using a different approach.

Comment: `By sendButton = By.id("button-submit");
By popUpClose = By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/button/span[1]");`

Comment: @plaidshirt, I have added the code snippet. Also, if you have already tried isDisplayed validation, could you check if the download button is actually being displayed? If yes, then check if the locator is correct and valid one for the same download button. If not, change the xpath for 'download' button and try.